# gnuclad does not change starting date

Tags: tree, gnuclad

I'm using `gnuclad` to create a tree. The problem is that I'm not able to change the starting date. I'm using the data below, from the default example.

```
#,Nodes,,,,,,,,,,,,,
#,Name,Color,Parent,Start,Stop,Icon,Description,[Namechange,When,Description,[Namechange,When,Description,". . . ]]"
N,Name here,#f00,,2002/12/01,2007/08/20,,,,,,,,,
```

As you can see on the image, the node starts always at January.

[image]

Also, is it possible to turn off the title box without editing the `conf` file?

The config file `example.conf` is the default one:

```
# gnuclad example config file
# gnuclad has more than 50 configuration options, of
# which only a few are listed here.
# For a detailed explanation, consult the included manual.
# You can always generate a full configuration file by
# specifying CONF as gnuclad's output.


# If you comment or delete an option,
# gnuclad will use the built-in defaults.
# Allowed syntax is:
#   option=value
#   option = value
#   option= 'value'
#   option ="value"
#   option = three word value
#   option = "three word value"
#   ...


infoBoxTitle = Title
infoBoxText = Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
infoBoxText = consectetuer adipiscing elit
infoBoxX = 10
infoBoxY = 45
infoBoxWidth = 166
infoBoxHeight = 60

# use ascii string width heuristics
asciiStrings = 1

# orientation goes from 0 to 3
orientation = 0

#treemode goes from 0 to 2
treeMode = 0

mainBackground = #fff
rulerWidth = 2
rulerColor = #ddd
rulerMonthWidth = 1
rulerMonthColor = #eaeaea

lineWidth = 4
offsetPX = 20
yearPX = 100

labelFontColor = #000
labelBGOpacity = 50

#nameChangeType can be 0 or 1
nameChangeType = 0

#derivType can be 0 or 1
derivType = 0
dotRadius = 10
smallDotRadius = 5

descriptionType = 1
```

Comment: Can you include the config file as well as the data file for this example? Just so that if others come across this in the future it's clear what you were doing and how you solved it.

Comment: @slm, edited. The data file is shown on the post.

Comment: Thank you! Also thanks for adding this to the site, never heard of this tool, looks interesting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnuclad/+bug/718191) I found the problem. The correct way to insert dates is using dots, e.g., 2012.03.10 and not slashes. The problem was the use of Gnumeric to edit the CSV file.